# Grouping attribute values on filters

Tags: magento2

Is there any plugin that allows grouping attribute values on filters? I want to achieve a situation where when someone chooses the "notebooks" category on our website, the filtering section does not show all screen dimensions individually (e.g., 13.1, 13.3, 13.6), but instead groups them into categories such as 13 inches and below, 14-16 inches, and 16 inches and above. It should also allow filtering products by these groups, with the option to expand each group to show the exact values of the attribute. For example, when clicking on "13 inches and above," the filters should extend to include options like 13.1, 13.3, and 13.6 inches.

This is the result i want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363599/i-need-filter-products-by-discount-percentage-in-layared-navigation-category-pa

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but note that this is not exactly what I need, I want the filter listing to be able to expand the group with the values ​​it contains.

Comment: Okay. Do you want this feature only for a particular attribute and particular category or a flexible solution for all attributes and all categories?